# can't show ng-template in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to have a `ng-repeat` show items from a `ng-template` however it doesn't show any items. How can that be?

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tree_renderer">
    <span>
        {{e.name}}
    </span>
</script>

<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="e in items"  ng-include="'tree_renderer'"></li>
        <li ng-repeat="e in items">
            {{e.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
'use strict';

angular.module('nodeTreeApp')
  .controller('NodeCtrl', function ($scope, $dialog, $http) {
    $scope.items = [
        {
            "name": "Root",
            "type_name": "Node",
            "show": true,
            "nodes": [{
                "name": "Loose",
                "group_name": "Node-1",
                "show": true,
                "nodes": [{
                    "name": "Node-1-1",
                    "device_name": "Node-1-1",
                    "show": true,
                    "nodes": []
                }, {
                    "name": "Node-1-2",
                    "device_name": "Node-1-2",
                    "show": true,
                    "nodes": []
                }, {
                    "name": "Node-1-3",
                    "device_name": "Node-1-3",
                    "show": true,
                    "nodes": []
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "God",
                "group_name": "Node-2",
                "show": true,
                "nodes": [{
                    "name": "Vadar",
                    "device_name": "Node-2-1",
                    "show": true,
                    "nodes": []
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "Borg",
                "group_name": "Node-3",
                "show": true,
                "nodes": []
            }, {
                "name": "Fess",
                "group_name": "Node-4",
                "show": true,
                "nodes": []
            }]
        }
    ];
});
```

```
'use strict';

angular.module('nodeTreeApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('node', {
        url: '/node',
        templateUrl: 'app/node/node.html',
        controller: 'NodeCtrl'
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.html` in your template `id` and `ng-include`.

I made this example based on (kinda) the code you provided: http://jsbin.com/qodayesigo/1/

**UPDATE**

To display the child nodes you need a nested ng-repeat, take a look at [this example](http://jsbin.com/kakafokuzi/1/).

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you can tell me why it only shows the first item in `items`?

Comment: I made a new example, does that make sense?